# Joomla active menu item id if statement

Tags: joomla

I am doing something to my client's Joomla page. The code is like this:

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu(); 
$arr = (array)$menu->getActive(); 
$alias = $arr['alias'];

echo $alias;

if ($alias = "volunteering-2") {

    echo('<div class="item-page">   <h2>Volunteering</h2></div>');
}
else if ($alias = "contact-us2") {

    echo('<div class="item-page">   <h2>Contact Us</h2></div>');
}
```

The problem is, the Contact Us H2 header is never appear, even the if statement is correct.
You can see the page here: http://dzulhel.me/yyDk9m

Try to see the page in Volunteering and Contact Us

I try tackle using ID instead of alias but it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. think you're missing "equal-to" sign.

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu(); 
$arr = (array)$menu->getActive(); 
$alias = $arr['alias'];

echo $alias;

if ($alias == "volunteering-2") {

 echo('<div class="item-page">   <h2>Volunteering</h2></div>');
}
else if ($alias == "contact-us2") {

echo('<div class="item-page">   <h2>Contact Us</h2></div>');
 }
```